# Jinja & Django Invalid block tag : 'set', expected 'endblock'

Tags: django, error-handling, jinja2

I need to increment the variable `count` but I'm getting this error, I have already searched, they say I should install jinja, however the code worked perfectly before adding `{% set count = 1 %}` , which means that it's not a matter of installation.
here is my Template code :

```
{% set count = 1 %}
        {% for form in formset %}

     <tr style="border:1px solid black;" id="{{ form.prefix }}-row" class="dynamic-form" >

        <td><div class="col-xs-1"><b><p name="np1">{{ count }}</p></b></div></td>
        <td >
            {% render_field form.dateOperation class="form-control"  %}{{form.dateOperation1.errors}}

        </td>
        <td>{% render_field form.designation  class="form-control"  %}{{form.errors}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {% render_field form.typeTiers class="form-control" %}{{form.typeTiers.errors}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {% render_field form.tiers class="form-control" %}{{form.tiers.errors}}
        </td>
        <td>{% render_field form.numfacture class="form-control"   %}{{form.numfacture.errors}}
        </td>
        <td>{% render_field form.montant class="form-control"  %}{{form.montantdebit.errors}}
        </td>
        {% for radio in form.typeMontant %}
        <td>

          {{ radio.tag }}
   </td>
         {% endfor %}
    <td>{% render_field form.montant class="form-control"  %} 
    {{form.montantdebit.errors}}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% set count = count + 1 %}
  {% endfor %}
```

and this is the raised error:

> Invalid block tag on line 51: 'set', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Any help please , Thank you in advance.

Comment: how can I make sure that Django is treating the template as jinja2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django has a {{ forloop.counter }}. You don't have to do it manually.

If you want to do math, use [django-mathfilters](https://github.com/dbrgn/django-mathfilters)

Comment: Similarly, Jinja2 has `loop.index0` and `loop.index` ([docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#list-of-control-structures)). However, from the error message, it sounds like the OP might be using regular Django templates instead of Jinja2.